# How to generate scripts corresponding to tool classes in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot package that consists of a bunch of tool classes, each with a main method. Is there a way to get a runnable script per tool class automatically?

The closest I have managed to get so far is to use the Spring Boot `PropertiesLauncher` launcher, so that I can write:

`LOADER_MAIN=com.foo.bar.ToolClass java -jar foo.jar ARGUMENT...`

But it would be nicer if I could write just `ToolClass ARGUMENT...` or `foo.jar ToolClass ARGUMENT...`.

The latter is easy to achieve with a short module that uses reflection to look up a class and then call its main method, but that's not exactly typesafe or automatic.

I also note that with Spring Boot CLI I could write Groovy scripts to achieve this result, but then I'd still have to call them with `spring run script`.

Another way of phrasing this question might be "how do I make a JAR automatically offer subcommands like git?". I see that several command-line argument parsing frameworks offer these sorts of commands, but I don't want to build it manually, I'd like it to be auto-discovered (and the sub-commands' argument parsing is left up to the sub-commands).

There's a Node.JS npm module, [helmsman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmsman), which does the equivalent in JavaScript: it turns a directory of scripts into sub-commands. I imagine that the Java equivalent should take even less effort to use, since it can use reflection to find all the main methods and then simply dispatch the command-line arguments to the given class.

Comment: Does it have to be Spring Boot?  Have you looked at Spring Shell?  http://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Spring Shell looks like it's for creating interactive applications for programming. I'm trying to create freestanding commands I can use from the shell, or, failing that, something like the "git" or "svn" command with subcommands. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: We use it as either.  We can start a spring shell and issue commands.  Or, we can provide the command as part of starting spring shell from the prompt.  So it will  work either way.  I just don't know if you can "turn off" the interactive shell

Comment: Can I just run one of these commands from the shell by its name, like any other shell command?

Comment: What we have done is written our own shell script that launches Spring Shell with the appropriate JAR file.  For the sake of this discussion, call it myShell.  If I run "myShell" from the command line, without any commands, it starts up an interactive shell.  If I run "myShell <command>", where <command> is one of my commands, the command will be run immediately.  Which behaves just like using a git or svn command line.  What I don't know if whether you can turn off interactivity and make a command mandatory.  If you can't have the interactive mode, maybe it's a problem

Comment: Thanks again. It's not quite what I was hoping for, but at least reduces the problem to writing a single script and some per-command annotations.